# Analytical approach when level of self-selected treatment variable is naturally reduced during course of longitudinal study

Tags: econometrics, panel-data, causality

I realized that some data I have collected may be able to make use of what I originally considered to be a nuisance issue that arose during data collection. I'm looking for input about whether I may be able to use econometric (or similar) approaches to take advantage of an exogenous, "natural" change to the treatment variable for some participants.

Basics:

- 3-wave panel survey (i.e., same group of people are surveyed with identical questions on 3 occasions)
- Hypothesized "treatment" is media consumption, assessed by aggregating responses to questions whether respondent watched Program A in past month, watched Program B in past month, etc. This means it is continuous and not experimentally manipulated.
- Between first and second panel wave (surveys 1 and 2), one of these programs was *cancelled* and taken off the air.
- Outcome variable is some psychological variable measured on each occasion.

Ignoring the cancellation, the basic challenge with the design is that participants self-select into the treatment; panel data models can protect against some but not all types of confounding.

It has occurred to me that the cancellation of the program may be useful from a causal inference standpoint. Some people, without choosing to do so, had their level of treatment reduced. This scenario seems to have some features in common with natural experiments but the particulars have me uncertain about which, if any, methods used for those problems might be applicable here. Specifically, the fact that the treatment is continuous (and computed as an index) and therefore not zeroed out by the quasi-manipulation makes me unsure if I really have something to work with here. It is also possible that respondents adjust their consumption of other programs to compensate for the cancellation of the one in question; in fact, I have wondered whether consumption of those other programs might be the proper outcome variable.

I suppose I could try to use the lagged level of cancelled program consumption as a predictor in a fixed effects (in the econometric sense) model, but I don't know that this would be making full use of the facts about the exogenous change on treatment level.